# Best way to code iterator in javascript

Tags: javascript, iterator

I'm building a complex object in Javascript and I want to expose an iterator over an internal collection of the object.

The only way I can think of is the usual way of exposing iterators in prototype.js :

```
customObject.each(function (item) { ... })
```

with the provided function being called by the iterator *each* for every item in the collection, one after the other.

Do you know any other reliable way? Maybe a way that would let users use the usual *foreach* construct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prototype style function is a good option, though you might also consider something like:

```
overlayRegistry = function() {
var overlays = [];
var index = 0;


return {
    addOverlay : function(overlay) {
            overlays.push(overlay);
    count : function() {
        return overlays.length;
    },
    reset : function() {
        index = 0;
    },
    next : function() {
        if (index < overlays.length) {
            return overlays[index++];
        } else {
            return null;
                    }
    },
    each : function (callback) {
        for (var index = 0, length = overlays.length; index < length; ++index) {
             callback(overlays[index]);
        }
    }

}
}();
```

In this case, you can iterate over it in steps while you wait for other events (as was the case behind this structure)

Basically, providing a method like `each` can work great if all you need is simple iteration, but if you need more control, then something like the above would work (of course, you could do both)

**Edit**
Added each method

Answer (score 1):

You should use `for in` instead.

```
>>> var customObject = {x: 1, y:2}
>>> for (a in customObject) console.log(a, customObject[a])
x 1
y 2
```

But remember about inherited properties.

```
>>>Object.prototype.yarrr = function yarrr(){ console.warn('YARRR!') }
>>> for (a in customObject) console.log(a, customObject[a])
x 1
y 2
yarrr()
>>> for (a in customObject) if (customObject.hasOwnProperty(a)) console.log(customObject[a])
x 1
y 2
```

Comment: Yea, but you'll want to make sure that customObject.hasOwnProperty(a) returns true for each method/property. Otherwise you could end up with inherited stuff.

Comment: Considering it is a complex object I can only presume it has methods which `for..in` will iterate over too.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, his custom object has an internal collection and he wants to provide a way to iterate over the elements in the internal collection, not the custom object's properties